# rig doesn't work correctly

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, weight-painting

[image]

I'm trying to rig my first organic model and the problem i have is that the sleeves disconnect with the body, the collar also moves along with the sleeve. I did this all with automatic weights.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your mesh and rigging is a bit a mess, first thing apply the *Mirror* modifier to simplify things, put the *Armature* at the top of the modifiers stack, do the same for the other parts of the body:

[image]

Select the arms and shift select the body, in *Edit* mode remove all these vertices from all groups:

[image]

Assign the same vertices to the correct vertex group (I've simplified the name), now they are all part of the same group and they should work correctly when you'll move the arm:

[image]

Comment: Seems to be working but when i move the left foot the sleeves also move. I updated the blend file